# How to check the n-th character in string , then update in new column Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

**Target** : if the **8th (or n of )** of character in string **match condition**, **then update in new column**

**By word in a single string :**

```
# if i want to check the 3rd character
IN[0]:  s = "apple"
        s[2]
OUT[0]: 'p'
```

**Code** :

```
tt = pd.DataFrame({"CC":["T020203J71500","Y020203K71500","T020407JLX100","P020403JLX100"])

tt["NAME"] = pd.np.where(tt["CC"][7].str.contains("J"),"JANICE",
               pd.np.where(tt["CC"][7].str.contains("K"),"KELVIN",
               pd.np.where(tt["CC"][7].str.contains("X"),"SPECIAL","NONE")))
```

**Problem** :
Apparently `[7]` is not a python practice

**In R data.table :**

```
tt[grepl("J",str_sub(CC,8,8)),
      "NAME":="JANICE"]
tt[grepl("K",str_sub(CC,8,8)),
      "NAME":="KELVIN"] # .... can achieve by doing like this
```

How can i do this in Python ?

Comment: sure , you are right EdChum , my typo

Answer (score 4):

Use [`series.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) to get the slice you are looking for then [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with the dictionary you have:

```
d={'J':'JANICE','K':'KELVIN','X':'SPECIAL'}
tt['Name']=tt['CC'].str[7].map(d).fillna('NONE')
print(tt)
```

---

```
              CC    Name
0  T020203J71500  JANICE
1  Y020203K71500  KELVIN
2  T020407JLX100  JANICE
3  P020403JLX100  JANICE
```

Comment: Thankyou again . Since R grepl () ; str_sub(x, start , end) provide flexibilities that can mix with : Pattern A --- check 7th = x, Pattern B --- check 7th to 8th = y . Is it good to just adding one more line & dictory for Pattern B 7th to 8th ? (probably overwrite the first line for 7th ?) bad for me didn't ask this at the beginning

Comment: @rane not sure if I understand but do you mean you want to replace a string by position. have a look at [`series.str.slice_replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.slice_replace.html) if that is the case

Comment: Dont want to intervene, but I think that changes your question quite a lot. I see this question as answered, you can ask a new question and explain your problem better there. @rane

Comment: I agree with @Erfan

Comment: Yes , i open a new question.

Comment: re-posted :   title --- :   How to check the single or multi n-th character in string , then update in new column Python

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) here since we have multiple conditions:

```
conditions = [
    tt['CC'].str[7].eq('J'),
    tt['CC'].str[7].eq('K'),
    tt['CC'].str[7].eq('X')
]

choices = ['JANICE', 'KELVIN', 'SPECIAL']

tt['NAME'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='NONE')
```

**Output**

```
              CC    NAME
0  T020203J71500  JANICE
1  Y020203K71500  KELVIN
2  T020407JLX100  JANICE
3  P020403JLX100  JANICE
```