# How to check the single or multi n-th character in string , then update in new column Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

**Target** : if the **single n-th (or multi n of ) of character(s)** in string **match condition**, **then update in new column**

**By word in a single string** :

```
# if i want to check the single 3rd character
IN[0]:  s = "apple"
        s[2]
OUT[0]: 'p'
# if i want to check the multi characters from n-th character to y-th character
IN[0]:  s = "apple"
        s[2:4]
OUT[0]: 'pl'
```

**Code** :

```
tt = pd.DataFrame({"CC":["T020203J71500","J0202029F51500","J020202GX51500"])

tt["NAME"] = pd.np.where(tt["CC"][7].str.contains("J"),"JANICE",
               pd.np.where(tt["CC"][7:9].str.contains("GX"),"GEN","NONE"))
```

**Problem** : Apparently `[7]` is not a python practice

**In R data.table** :

```
tt[,"NAME":="JANICE"]

tt[grepl("J",str_sub(CC,8,8)), # <-- single character
      "NAME":="JANICE"]

tt[grepl("GX",str_sub(CC,8,9)), # <-- multi characters
      "NAME":="GEN"] # .... can achieve by doing like this
```

How can i do this in Python ?

Comment: why is indexing a string not python practice?

Comment: I don't fully understand what your desired output is but replacing `[7]` and `[7:9]` with `.str.slice(7)` and `.str.slice(7, 9)` will give you an expression that at least has valid syntax, and may be what you're after.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check the n-th character in string , then update in new column Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57200052/how-to-check-the-n-th-character-in-string-then-update-in-new-column-python)

Comment: thankyou  thesilkworm , i think its most close to R function of str_sub()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your correctly (since you didn't provide an expected output), we can use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with multiple conditions:

```
choices = [
    tt['CC'].str[7].eq('J'),
    tt['CC'].str[7:9].eq('GX')
]

conditions = ['JANICE', 'GEN']

tt['NAME'] = np.select(choices, conditions, default='NONE')
```

**Output**

```
               CC    NAME
0   T020203J71500  JANICE
1  J0202029F51500    NONE
2  J020202GX51500     GEN
```

Answer (score 1):

use apply function with custom function in it.

```
tt = pd.DataFrame({"CC": ["T020203J71500", "J0202029F51500", "J020202GX51500"]})


def check_substring(x):
    if str(x)[7] == 'J':
        return "JANICE"
    elif str(x)[7:9] == "GX":
        return "GEN"
    return None


tt['Name'] = tt["CC"].apply(lambda x: check_substring(x))
```

```
             CC    Name
0   T020203J71500  JANICE
1  J0202029F51500    None
2  J020202GX51500     GEN
```